# to-many fault not fired when passing objectID between contexts

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have two contexts: parentContext and childContext. When I try to pass an objectID from the childContext to the parentContext, a fault is not fired for the to-many relationship in the parentContext.

The to-many relationship is called "categories" and is unordered (NSSet).

```
NSManagedObjectContext *parentContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
childContext.parentContext = parentContext;
childContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;

NSSet *childObjects = [childContext registeredObjects];

[childContext save:NULL];

[parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    for (NSManagedObject *childObject in childObjects) {
        NSManagedObject *parentObject = [parentContext objectWithID:childObject.objectID];
        // [parentObject hasFaultForRelationshipNamed:@"categories"]; returns false
        // [childObject hasFaultForRelationshipNamed:@"categories"]; // returns true as expected
        [parentContext refreshObject:parentObject mergeChanges:YES];
    }
}];
```

I want the "categories" relationship to fault even in the parentContext. Can you please help?

Comment: Did you try to access the relationship? Not clear what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Yes, when I try to access the relationship in parentObject, it doesn't trigger a fault as expected.

Comment: How about after refresh? Still not clear which problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: After saving the objects in the childContext, I want the changes to propagate to the parentContext. So, I'm trying to refresh the objects in the parentContext, but when I try to access the relationship, no faults are triggered and I always get an empty set. I get the same behavior after refresh as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you also have to save the parent context. The child context save only "pushes" the changes up to the parent context, but they are not saved to the store at this point.

Your faults should fire once the parent context is saved.